# Using a reg ex to strip out dashes, commas, and non-numeric characters but dashes aren't being stripped properly when numbers are added together

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below JS in order to strip out commas, dashes, and any non-numeric characters. However if I put say "---"then the number, the calculated value is still not adding correctly and becomes a negative number. This has me stumped. Can anyone see what's happening? Thanks, it's in the `var result` block.

```
    var $recurringCostField = $('#am_attribute_campaign_addon_monthly_cost_value');
    var $recurringTotalCostField = $('#am_attribute_campaign_addon_total_monthly_cost_value');
    var $totalRetailAmountField = $('#am_total_retail_amount');
    var $totalRetailAmountFieldLabel = $('label[for=am_total_retail_amount]');
    var $oneTimeCostField = $('#am_attribute_campaign_addon_one_time_cost_value');

//Calculate One time cost and total recurring cost
function calcTotalRetailVal() {
    var num1 = $oneTimeCostField.val();
    var num2 = $recurringTotalCostField.val();
    var result = parseFloat(num1.replace(/(,|[^\d.-]+)+/g, '')) + parseFloat(num2.replace(/(,|[^\d.-]+)+/g, ''));

            if (!isNaN(result)) {
                $totalRetailAmountField.text('$' + result.toFixed(2));
            }   
        }
        calcTotalRetailVal();
                $oneTimeCostField.on("keydown keyup", function() {
                    calcTotalRetailVal();
             });
             $recurringTotalCostField.on("keydown keyup", function() {
                calcTotalRetailVal();
             });
```

Comment: tldr. Pls simplify description. No interested in business logic.

Comment: `/(,|[^\d.-]+)+/` Your regex allows dashes. Try `/(,|[^\d]+)+/`

Comment: If you just don't want any nonumerical characters then just do `[^\d]+`

Comment: thanks, the issue seems to happen when there's a "-" then the number gets added before the reg ex strips the character.